Identify movie only by quote heard in YT clip
I've asked best possible place to ask about this, and this question brought me here. 
I found a quote that I might not be properly deciphering, here, exact time, with about 15 sec duration. I've tried basic googling as I heard it: 

we're looking for a meaning, what is the meaning, ** take jobs vacations that's ** finest trips human mind ** largest inspirations

but google turned up nothing...
I'd be happy if anyone could provide any pointers, or exact answer.

"and this question brought me here." - Not really, it has no answers yet.

see comment below question - suggesting that sci-fi uses "story-identification" tag where movies use multiple different (like identify-this-movie, identify-series, etc.)

Sure, but nobody on that question said yet, that identifying the source of some arbitrary YouTube clip is on-topic here.

True, so i guess it was plain luck that malformed quote turned to be from movie, and thus identifiable (what's more - so quickly by Walt, people'll never cease to amaze me). Yet, if someone had proper quote quick google search yields proper result. So perhaps I'm mistaken here, but it seems that  tag "identify-*" should be related to something that's non-findable easy way.

Happened to recognize McConaughey's drawl, but TBH Napoleon's right. It turned out to be a film quote, but could've been from anything.

@JustMe Well, with a bit of luck (and given the fact it got an accepted answer so fast), this question might survive here, since the quality and closing rules on identification questions are still a bit fuzzy in some areas and the community is often insecure of closing bad identification questions. But nevertheless this question doesn't seem to be a good fit here, as explained in one of the answers on your respective meta question.

You're looking for Contact from 1997, though you transcribed some things wrong. The quote is by Palmer (Matthew McConaughey):

We’re looking for the meaning, well what is the meaning? We have mindless jobs, we take frantic vacations. Deficit finance trips to the mall to buy more things that we feel are gonna fill these holes in our lives. Is it any wonder that we’ve lost our sense of direction?

